# How to assign id dynamically to xsl fo block which is inside my for loop?

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I want to call a xsl fo block which is generated inside for loop with hyperlink. I would like to assign different id to the  block in every iteration of for loop. So that i can call different blocks at different locations. Please suggest any approach.

Please have a look at my xslt below.

```
<fo:basic-link internal-destination="$BlockId" color="blue">  
    <xsl:value-of select="sampledetail/field[@id='SampleNo']/text()" />
</fo:basic-link>
.
.
.
.
<xsl:for-each select="report/content">
   <xsl:variable name="BlockId">
      <xsl:value-of select="sampledetail/field[@id='SampleNo']/text()" />
   </xsl:variable>
   <fo:block id="**$BlockId**">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="sampledetail" />
   </fo:block>
<xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: You could probably make use of `position()` here, but to get a proper answer you will need to edit your question to show some input XML, the XSLT you currently have and the output you expect. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you should be using [Attribute Value Templates](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-10/#attribute-value-templates) here. So, the syntax you should use is this...

```
<fo:block id="{$BlockId}">
```

So, maybe your sample code should look like this

```
<xsl:for-each select="report/content">
   <xsl:variable name="BlockId" select="sampledetail/field[@id='SampleNo']/text()" />
   <fo:basic-link internal-destination="{$BlockId}" color="blue">  
      <xsl:value-of select="$BlockId" />
   </fo:basic-link>
</xsl:for-each>
.
.
.
.
<xsl:for-each select="report/content">
   <xsl:variable name="BlockId" select="sampledetail/field[@id='SampleNo']/text()" />
   <fo:block id="{$BlockId}">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="sampledetail" />
   </fo:block>
<xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Working as expected. :)